# 95% HPD Region Using R TeachingDemos Package

Tags: r, bayesian

I need to find a 95% HPD Region using the TeachingDemos package in R. I have a posterior distribution that follows a gamma distribution.

After installing the package and typing in library(TeachingDemos),

I did:

```
a = 200 
b = 20
hpd(qgamma,shape1=a,shape2=b, conf=0.95)
```

(a and b are the alpha and beta values of the Gamma distribution)

I keep getting the following error message when I run my code:

```
 Error in posterior.icdf(1 - conf + x, ...) : 
  unused arguments (shape1 = 200, shape2 = 20)
```

I'm a total newbie at using R, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Type `?hpd` into the R console for help. Also this is a programming question and not really a statistics question -- it's better to post these on StackOverflow using the `r` tag.

Comment: @ssdecontrol I don't know what the error message is trying to say. ?hpd is not telling me anything new. My code works if I change qgamma to qbeta, but I need my code to work for qgamma.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: it seems that you might be confusing the beta (shape1, shape2) and gamma (shape, scale or rate,scale) distributions?

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `hpd` is

```
hpd(posterior.icdf, conf=0.95, tol=0.00000001,...)
```

And the documentation states that `...` is "additional arguments passed to posterior.icdf." That means that, somewhere inside `hpd`, there is a line of code that looks something like

```
posterior.icdf(x, ...)
```

where `...` is just whatever arguments were passed to ``` hpd`` apart from ```conf`and`tol`.

If you look at the function signature for `qbeta` you'll see that it has arguments `shape1` and `shape2`. Whereas if you look at `qgamma` you'll find that those are *not* valid argument names.

You will get the same error message if you call `qgamma` directly with those arguments, e.g.

```
qgamma(0.5, shape1=200, shape2=20)
```